# will array_view.synchronize_asynch wait for parallel_for_each completion?

Tags: c++, c++-amp

If I have a `concurrency::array_view` being operated on in a `concurrency::parallel_for_each` loop, my understanding is that I can continue other tasks on the CPU while the loop is executing:

```
using namespace Concurrency;

array_view<int> av;
parallel_for_each(extent<1>(number),[=](index<1> idx)
{
  // do some intense computations on av
}

// do some stuff on the CPU while we wait

av.synchronize(); // wait for the parallel_for_each loop to finish and copy the data
```

But what if I want to *not wait* for the parallel for loop but start copying data back from the GPU *as soon as possible*. Will the following work?

```
using namespace Concurrency;

array_view<int> av;
parallel_for_each(extent<1>(number),[=](index<1> idx)
{
  // do some intense computations on av
}

// I know that we won't be waiting to synch when I call this, but will we be waiting here
// until the data is available on the GPU end to START copying?
completion_future waitOnThis = av.synchronize_asynch();

// will this line execute before parallel_for_each has finished processing, or only once it
// has finished processing an the data from "av" has started copying back?

completion_future.wait();
```

I read about this topic on [The Moth](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/parallelforeach-from-amph-part-1.aspx), but after reading the following I'm not really any wiser:

> Please note that the parallel_for_each executes as if synchronous to
>   the calling code, but in reality, it is asynchronous. I.e. once the
>   parallel_for_each call is made and the kernel has been passed to the
>   runtime, the some_code_B region continues to execute immediately by
>   the CPU thread, while in parallel the kernel is executed by the GPU
>   threads. However, if you try to access the (array or array_view) data
>   that you captured in the lambda in the some_code_B region, your code
>   will block until the results become available. Hence the correct
>   statement: the parallel_for_each is as-if synchronous in terms of
>   visible side-effects, but asynchronous in reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the way this has been explained. A better way to think about it is that the `parallel_for_each` queues work to the GPU, so it returns almost immediately. There are numerous ways that your CPU-side code can block until the queued work is complete, for example, explicitly calling `synchronize`, or accessing data from one of the `array_view` instances used within the `parallel_for_each`

```
using namespace concurrency;

array_view<int> av;
parallel_for_each(extent<1>(number),[=](index<1> idx)
{
  // Queue (or schedule if you like) some intense computations on av
}
```

Host code can execute now. The AMP computations may or may not have started. If the code here accesses `av` then it will block until the work on the GPU is complete and the data in `av` has been written and can be synchronized with the host memory.

This is a future so it is also a scheduled task. It is not guaranteed to
execute at any particular point. Should it be scheduled then it will block the thread it is running on until `av` is correctly synchronized with the host memory (as above).

```
completion_future waitOnThis = av.synchronize_asynch();
```

More host code can execute here. If the host code accesses `av` then it will block until the `parallel_for_each` has completed (as above). At some point the runtime will execute the future and block until `av` has synchronized with the host memory. If it is writable and has been changed then it will be copied back to the host memory.

```
completion_future.wait();
```

The call to `wait` will block until the future has completed (prior to calling `wait` there is no guarantee that anything has actually executed). At this point you are guaranteed that the GPU calculations are complete and that `av` can be accessed on the CPU.

Having said all that adding the `waitOnThis` future seems to be over complicating matters.

```
array_view<int> av;
parallel_for_each(extent<1>(number),[=](index<1> idx)
{
  // do some intense computations on av on the GPU
}

// do some independent CPU computation here.

av.synchronize();

// do some computation on the CPU that relies on av here.
```

The MSDN docs aren't very good on this topic. The following [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/02/20/synchronizing-array-view-in-c-amp.aspx) is better. There are some other posts on the async APIs on the same blog.

Comment: Thanks, this has been helpful. So just to confirm, `array_view::synchronize_async()` will block absolutely nothing in itself, it will only instruct the underlying data to be transferred *when* whatever kernel was working on it has finished, yes?

Comment: Yes, (the MSDN doc is pretty sparse on this). You can think of it as queueing a copy operation for the array_view, as some point this will get executed.