# C++ AMP Performance Issue - Dramatic Inconsistent Performance without any data movement

Tags: c++, c++-amp

I have an algorithm that relies upon approx. 15 different array_views, and 8 different for_each AMP kernel calls.   The nature of the algorithm is that all of the data is copied to the GPU and then a set of kernel calls are executed over and over until some threshold is reached.  Note:  I have not yet implemented the threshold logic - which would require retrieving the data back to the CPU.

The complete set of kernel calls is called a cycle.    In between each cycle, I do not reference any of the array_view data on the CPU....thus, I do not expect any data movement back to the CPU.    However, the performance of the cycles is not regular.   Most of the time the cycles take 10 or so milliseconds but then every 3rd or 4th cycle (or sometimes back to back), the cycle takes 400 or 500 of milliseconds to execute.    The internal logic of the kernel calls is always basically the same.....so the increased execution time is not due to GPU logic.

What might be causing the dramatic increase in time for some cycles?    See sample timings below.

Time to complete first cycle 503.278 (ms)
This time includes overhead of AMP initialization, kernel compilation, and data
movement to the GPU.

Time to complete 1 more cycles: 11.3105 (ms)
Time to complete 2 more cycles: 10.7455 (ms)
Time to complete 3 more cycles: 538.668 (ms)
Time to complete 4 more cycles: 13.3055 (ms)
Time to complete 5 more cycles: 14.4544 (ms)
Time to complete 6 more cycles: 12.353 (ms)
Time to complete 7 more cycles: 17.5154 (ms)
Time to complete 8 more cycles: 755.255 (ms)
Time to complete 9 more cycles: 11.7461 (ms)
Time to complete 10 more cycles: 14.6612 (ms)
Time to complete 11 more cycles: 417.788 (ms)
Time to complete 12 more cycles: 399.167 (ms)
Time to complete 13 more cycles: 12.2898 (ms)
Time to complete 14 more cycles: 16.9694 (ms)
Time to complete 15 more cycles: 151.228 (ms)
Time to complete 16 more cycles: 404.659 (ms)
Time to complete 17 more cycles: 10.4977 (ms)
Time to complete 18 more cycles: 15.7178 (ms)
Time to complete 19 more cycles: 207.768 (ms)
Time to complete 20 more cycles: 511.538 (ms)
Time to complete 21 more cycles: 14.4339 (ms)
Time to complete 22 more cycles: 252.77 (ms)
Time to complete 23 more cycles: 504.565 (ms)
Time to complete 24 more cycles: 12.6931 (ms)
Time to complete 25 more cycles: 15.5403 (ms)
Time to complete 26 more cycles: 303.68 (ms)
Time to complete 27 more cycles: 440.331 (ms)
Time to complete 28 more cycles: 8.63698 (ms)
Time to complete 29 more cycles: 13.9312 (ms)
Time to complete 30 more cycles: 755.637 (ms)
Exiting......
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Can you please share (at least a pseudo-code) how you are measuring the time, note C++ AMP team has a blog post on the topic: [How to measure the performance of C++ AMP algorithms?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/12/28/how-to-measure-the-performance-of-c-amp-algorithms.aspx). Also interesting is make and model of the GPU your are using and whether this unit is dedicated to the computation, or is there anything else running in background that might be using it.

Comment: Graphics card is AMD Radeon HD 6130.   Regarding the timing approach....I am using the same method used in the C++ AMP book.  See sample code following:  for (i=1; i<=500; i++)
{
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);  //execute 500 cycles and compare performance
  AMPFuncs(myView, parms, avDirects, avPatterns, avErrors, avActuals);
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
  std::wcout << "Time to complete " << i  << " more cycles: " << ElapsedTime(start, end) << " (ms)" << std::endl;
}

Comment: Only using 50% of GPU dedicated memory and the GPU is being used both for my computations and the laptop display although I am not actively doing anything on the display at the time the computations are running.

Comment: In AMPFuncs, how are you synchronizing CPU and GPU - do you use accelerator_view::wait() in every call?

Apart from that, we have observed AMD performing quite aggressive power stepping, even on desktop systems, which I'd expect to be exaggerated on laptop - to this extent you can try tweaking Windows power settings, or maybe some options in the Catalyst Control Center. Having said that ~50x jumps sound to me way too steep to be explained by this.

Comment: Outline source code (and some reformatting of your question) would really help here. I't hare to read your perf counter code but I don't see a flush() or wait() in your comment so it's possible that your are not really timing each call separately. Remember AMP kernel execution is not really execution it's queuing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830470/will-array-view-synchronize-asynch-wait-for-parallel-for-each-completion for more details on timing and queuing.

Comment: I run in immediate mode and have a view.wait() after every kernel call.   I have updated my driver and looking at the Catalyst Center options.    I will let you know if I find anything.